# Ascertaining controller and action from my own class in CakePHP 2.4

Tags: php, cakephp

I have created a class of my own which I'm using from methods which override those in a couple of Cake's caching-related classes in order to customise the filenames of the files that `CacheHelper` saves. (The filenames sometimes need to include the type of user so that logged in users don't see cached versions of what non-logged in users would see and vice-versa, for example.)

My class is called `MyCacheUtility` and resides in `app/Lib/Cache`.

In this class, I need to ascertain what the controller and action are. What is the best way of doing so, and can I use Cake's `CakeRequest` class?

So far, I have included `App::uses('CakeRequest', 'Network');`, and...

I can't use `$this->params('controller')` as my class isn't a controller or component:

```
Error: Using $this when not in object context
File: /srv/www/app/Lib/Cache/MyCacheUtility.php
Line: 20
```

I can't use `CakeRequest::param('controller')` as (if I understand correctly) `CakeRequest`'s methods are not designed to be used statically:

```
Error: Using $this when not in object context
File: /srv/www/cakephp/lib/Cake/Network/CakeRequest.php
Line: 864
```

The contents of my class:

```php
App::uses('CakeRequest', 'Network');

class MyCacheUtility {

/**
 * Sets the cache file’s filename to include references to user type
 * and organisation (depending on the current controller and action)
 * so that both logged-in users from different organisations and visitors
 * get the right stuffs.
 */
    public static function getPrefix() {

        $prefix = '';

        switch ('controller') . '/' . 'action') { // this is where I need the controller and action

            case 'user_lists/organisation_lists':
                $prefix .= MyCacheUtility::sessionDataToFilename('currentUser.organisationName');
                break;

        }

        $prefix .= MyCacheUtility::sessionDataToFilename('currentUser.type');

        return $prefix;

    }

/**
 *
 */
    private static function sessionDataToFilename($sessionValue) {

        if (CakeSession::read($sessionValue)) {
            return strtolower(Inflector::slug(CakeSession::read($sessionValue))) . '-';
        }

    }

}
```

**Update:**

I found I wasn't able to pass the `CakeRequest` object from `CacheDispatcher` to `MyCacheUtility` class, and I think this is because CakeRequest has not been instantiated at the point at which `CacheDispatcher` does its stuff?

I do now have what I set out to do working. I'm passing Cake's `$path` variable through to my method and manually doing some processing based on this:

```php
class MyCacheUtility {

    public static function getPrefix($path) {

        $pathParts = explode('/', parse_url($path, PHP_URL_PATH));

        $prefix = '';

        if (count($pathParts) > 1) {
            if ($pathParts[1] == 'shared_lists') {
                $prefix .= MyCacheUtility::sessionDataToFilename('currentUser.organisationName');
            }
        }

        $prefix .= MyCacheUtility::sessionDataToFilename('currentUser.type');

        return $prefix;

    }

    private static function sessionDataToFilename($sessionValue) {

        if (CakeSession::read($sessionValue)) {
            return strtolower(Inflector::slug(CakeSession::read($sessionValue))) . '-';
        }

    }

}
```

I was hoping to be able to directly apply Cake's own logic, but this seems to be doing the job okay so far.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need a library class at all? Extend the CacheHelper and use your customized cache helper via aliasing as `$this->Cache` in the views. To modify the file names it should be enough to override [CacheHelper::_writeFile()](http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/source-class-CacheHelper.html#__writeFile).

If you want to modify the caching itself write a new cache engine or extend an existing one to modify it's behavior. Your question does not really contain much information about why and what exactly you want to do so I can't give a better advice.

The CakeRequest object should be nearly everywhere present, so just pass it to the constructor of your cache lib. But like I said, architecturewise I doubt your approach is the best path to go. Show your cache lib code?

```
new MyCacheLib(CakeRequest $request);
```

**Edit:**

Write your custom Cache dispatcher or extend the existing one instead. You'll get the request object passed to it by default. Take a look at [the CacheDispatcher filter](http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/source-class-CacheDispatcher.html). No need for a lib class here.

A more simple approach might be to write a custom cache engine and configure the helper to use that, same for the cache dispatcher filter. This way you can share the code. Or use a trait (php 5.4) to share the path building logic between the filter and the helper.

Comment: Thanks. I created a new file/class because I need to use the same logic to determine what the file should be/is called from both the helper and the dispatcher (when looking for cache files to serve), so I can call my method from both places without duplicating code. Should I instead put my method in `MyCacheHelper` and then call `MyCacheHelper->myMethod` from `MyCacheDispatcher->beforeDispatch`? In the meantime, I'll try using your code example to pass through the CakeRequest object.

Comment: In response to your edit, I have extended the existing Cache dispatcher, but that's not where I need to find the controller and action. I need these from my utility class, which was thinking both `MyCacheHelper` and `MyCacheDispatcher` would use. But I'll look into the options you mentioned. Thanks again.

Comment: Well, you said "...and the dispatcher (when looking for cache files to serve)..." . So this should be the right place. However, I would not work around the framework with a custom lib but instead work with the framework by using the concepts and things it offers.

Comment: There are two separate classes (which both extend existing Cake classes) in which I need to apply my custom logic: `MyCacheHelper` (to save the cache file) and `MyCacheDispatcher` (to use the previously-saved cache file) - this is why I created a new class in Lib just for establishing the prefix, which is made up of various characters depending on the controller and action. I understand that you're saying a new Lib isn't necessary, but where should this logic that is used in two places go?

Comment: In a custom cache engine. The dispatcher and helper would just use the engine and the engine takes care of your path prefixing.

Comment: `$event->data['request']` shows controller and action as `null` when I use the debug function with it from `MyCacheDispatcher`.